# Splitting several kinds of identical objects amongst a number of non-empty groups

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, binomial-coefficients, inclusion-exclusion

The question is as follows:
Split 10 Cs, 7 Gs, 6 Ls and 3 Ks between 4 boxes. Each box should get at least one thing.
The solution is below:

$$ \binom{13}{3} \binom{10}{3}\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}-4\cdot\binom{12}
{2}\binom{9}{2}\binom{8}{2}\binom{5}{2}+6\cdot 11 \cdot 8\cdot7\cdot4-4$$

I don't understand it. The first part is the total number of ways to split the things no matter whether the boxes are empty or not. The second part is what? The third? Fourth?

Comment: The second term is the number of arrangements with at least one empty box, the third is the number with at least two empty boxes, and the the last is the number with three empty boxes; this is an application of the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: Thank you, I was uncertain but now it clicked for me. If you write it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I’m glad that it helped; I’ve posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second term is a first approximation to the number of arrangements with at least one empty box, the third (over)corrects for overcounting the arrangements with at least two empty boxes, and the last is the number with three empty boxes, compensating for the overcorrection; this is an application of the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: Well, those terms are really *overcounts* of those  arrangements.

Comment: @RobPratt: If we’re *really* being fussy, only the first two are overcounts. :-) When I posted it, I figured that the OP understood what was going on well enough to make sense of the shorthand, but it really would be better to be a bit more precise, and I’ve modified it accordingly.